# The element type "h:column" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</h:column>"

Tags: jsp, jsf

I am getting the above error in the following line. The tag is seems to be properly closed but still the error there.

```
...
 <h:column>
   <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
     <h:commandButton value="Delete" 
                                 action="#{userData.deleteEmployee(employee)}"  />                
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close the command button twice. Delete  `</h:commandButton>` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<h:commandButton>` tag is terminated twice. That's confusing your parser. You have:

```
<h:commandButton ... />
```

and then:

```
</h:commandButton>
```

Remove the `</h:commandButton>` line and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

either change to

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" 
action="#{userData.deleteEmployee(employee)}"  >                
</h:commandButton>
```

or

```
<h:commandButton value="Delete" 
action="#{userData.deleteEmployee(employee)}"  />
```